# Set single dimension array from while loop PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello Im trying to make new array from my mysqli results into single array.

How can I achieve it? I tried this code but its not working well.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("****");

    $sql = "SELECT foo FROM foo";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();

$stmt->bind_result($foo);

$ids = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
 $ids[] = $foo;
}
```

The final array should be single dimension something like this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5...}
```

Comment: So, what *does* `$ids` look like?

Comment: I don't think you need `$stmt->store_result();` here.  Get rid of that line.

Comment: I need to check. You think that this code should work?

Comment: If you remove `store_result()` it looks like it should.

Comment: `while ($foo = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $ids[] = $foo;
}` asign value to `$foo`.

Comment: @Poldas: No.  Not with MySQLi.  You're thinking PDO, it's very different.  `bind_result()` takes a *reference* to `$foo`, `fetch()` will update that reference with the next value.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You're right. Missed this line `$stmt->bind_result($foo);`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: When I try my code with echo $ids; I get "Array".
I know that there is value because I also do echo $foo; and I do see values.